# Pop up to display a video with datalife engine tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, datalife-engine

i need some help with javascript and datalife engine.

I have a youtube video on my posts, that are displayed calling on the .tpl files(template files) the tag

```
[xfvalue_treyler]
```

Basicly this fetches the info that is on the field "treyler" on that specific post. In my case, that value is the iframe code to the youtube video.

I have been researching and i found this javascript code for what i want to use.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var self = $(this) //button
    , content = $('.content'); 

    $('element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
        onOpen: function() {
            content.html(self.data('bpopup') || '');
        },
        onClose: function() {
            content.empty();
        }
    });
</script>
```

and i call it by using

```
<div class="element_to_pop_up">[xfvalue_online]</div>
```

I gave some random css just to define the class "element_to_pop_up", but for some reason this doesn't seem to work. Can you give me a example of this code working on a jsfiddle page please?

Comment: Have you tried changing `$('element_to_pop_up')` to `$('.element_to_pop_up')`?

Comment: I did now. What i basicly have is the trailer wrapped in the box that i defined for the CSS style. I guess i'm calling it the wrong way...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BHLmD/1/ This is basicly what i have. As you know i can't use the tag [xfvalue_treyler] in there so i have to use the iframe code itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, by the looks of things you are having trouble with [jQuery.bPopup.js](http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/), so here is a basic example which should hopefully point you in the right direction.

**HTML:**

```
<button class="trailerbutton" data-trailerid="whatever">Pop Trailer</button>
<div class="hiddenTrailer" id="whatever">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/jGGIgcFgnOk?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div id="my-popup">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function() {
    $('.trailerbutton').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var content = $('.content');
        var trailerid = $(this).data('trailerid');
        var trailerhtml = $('#' + trailerid).html();

        $('#my-popup').bPopup({
            onOpen: function() {
                content.html(trailerhtml || '');
            },
            onClose: function() {
                content.empty();
            }
        });
    });    
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.hiddenTrailer {
    display: none;
}

#my-popup { 
    display:none;    
    background-color: #2B91AF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

In my example, I have chosen to popup trailers via a button with a common class of `trailerbutton`. This allows me to use common JS code for all `trailerbutton` click events.

I have also chosen to hide my YouTube iframe inside a div just below the button. Note that this has a class of `hiddenTrailer` which is hidden via the CSS.

As you can see, I store the ID of the trailer div I want to show for each button in the `data-trailerid` attribute.

I also have a hidden "popup" placeholder, called `my-popup`, which again is hidden with CSS.

When the user clicks the button, the JS event is fired, and the correct trailer is loaded into the content div in the ready and waiting popup, based on that all important data attribute.

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vqJy4/). Note that I've had to paste the entire jQuery.bPopup.min.js into the JavaScript window, so scroll down to check out the real content.

**EDIT:**

Should you wish this to work for multiple posts, you can do something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<button class="trailerbutton">Pop Trailer</button>
<div class="hiddenTrailer">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/jGGIgcFgnOk?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<button class="trailerbutton">Pop Trailer</button>
<div class="hiddenTrailer">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/fZ_JOBCLF-I" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div id="my-popup">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function() {
    $('.trailerbutton').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var content = $('.content');
        var trailerhtml = $(this).next('.hiddenTrailer').html();

        $('#my-popup').bPopup({
            onOpen: function() {
                content.html(trailerhtml || '');
            },
            onClose: function() {
                content.empty();
            }
        });
    });    
});
```

The updated line here is `var trailerhtml = $(this).next('.hiddenTrailer').html();` - I am now using jQuery to select the next `hiddenTrailer` element (i.e. - the one just under the button you pressed).

[See this updated Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/vqJy4/3/)

Comment: I got a problem, i don't know if you can help. The button doesn't fetch individual content... what i mean is, if the 1º post, when i see the trailer of the 2º post, it will be the same... But it should be another one

Comment: thank you for the patience. I've tested but i don't think this will work in Datalife Engine. We call the posts using a tag named {content}. This tag retrieves the posts, and uses a .tpl file that defines the style(You could call it the default html for one post i guess). I'm editing this file to put the code of the trailer. But i can only change one that will have to work on all :/ I've puted the div trailercontainer, but it doesn't work. Still getting the same for all

Comment: @PedroLino - I have now simplified my update, does this help? Be sure to update the JavaScript as well as the template. I'm afraid that I don't have any experience with the Datalife Engine, but hopefully this will push you towards a solution that works for you.